# How do I nicely read an unknown number of objects from java.io.ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, serialization, file-io

I found [this page](http://www.javadb.com/reading-objects-from-file-using-objectinputstream) that suggests looping until exceptions is thrown and then handle that exception.

Basically what it suggests is:

```
[...]
try {
    while (true) {
        objectInputStream.readObject();
    }
}
catch ( EOFException e ) {
    \\ This ALWAYS happens
}
[...]
```

However as Bloch put it in Effective Java, one should only "Use exceptions for exceptional conditions" and there isn't really anything exceptional about the inputstream not containing an infinite number of objects now is there? It is going to happen every single time!

Since there is no `hasNext` method on the ObjectInputStream, what can I do? Am I really stuck with using an Exception for knowing when there are no more Objects available to read?

Comment: Put them all into a single array/`List` and read that in one go? (Both array and `List` have problems here (reference arrays generally bad, generic objects are good as a root with deserialisation), so probably best off deserialising a "custom" meaningful object.)

Comment: Yea, but no I don't want to hold the entire contents of the file in memory at the same time...

Comment: They'll be in memory anyway due to back references. (`readUnshared` is unlikely to actually help you either.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A number of ways to do this, all of them fine, in my opinion:

- use the exception. The API designers didn't include a method, as you said, to check whether there is more, so it's partly their fault
- use a marker object when writing to the stream. For example `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or a custom `EOFMarker` object. If it is found, stop.
- Don't write the objects themselves, but write a `List` instead. Then read the list

Comment: The third alternative is not an option for me cause I need to write things to file since I can't keep them in memory and in order to write a list I would need to keep the list in memory...
I really like the second variant though :)

Comment: I'd go for the last. The exception could come from anywhere, any may be indicating, say, truncated data. If I was going to use a marker object, I think I'd use an object (probably an enum instance) made for the specific purpose.

Comment: @Tom yeah, I just addedthe `EOFMarker` as an alternative to `MAX_VALUE`

Comment: An alternative to EOFMarker is to use a `null`. EOFMarker is clearer haowever.

Comment: If you know how many objects you are writing _before_ you start writing, you can write that value first (that's basically how a list is Serialized anyway).

Comment: Another approach is to send a boolean with writeBoolean/readBoolean before each object as a `hasNext` to say there is no more data.